# Cronjob does not work on rake command

Tags: ruby, linux, cron, rake, redmine

I am totally stuck on a cronjob command which does not want to work.

Here is my problem :

I just want to launch a rake command on my crontab (for Redmine : check all unread emails on a specific address through IMAP and create a redmine ticket)

Here is the command :

```
cd /opt/redmine/ && rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.gmail.com username=redmine.check@gmail.com ssl=true port=993 password=MyPassword project=level1support unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1 allow_override=project
```

I am able to launch this on my command line and everything works fine

So I made a `crontab -e` and add this line on my crontab :

```
*/10 * * * * cd /opt/redmine/ && rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.gmail.com username=redmine.check@gmail.com ssl=true port=993 password=MyPassword project=level1support unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1 allow_override=project
```

But it does not work.

The cron seems to run (it is OK in my `/var/log/cron` file)

I added a log file on this cron like this (at the end of the line) `> /tmp/crontabRedmin.log 2&>1` but nothing is written on the log file.

I created a .sh script, I tried different syntaxes for the rake command (`/usr/local/bin/rake` or `&& RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake`), everything works on my command line , but nothing through the cron.

Please help me to know, what am I missing.

Comment: Are you using something to manage your ruby installations or do you use the unix/linux package manager to install ruby and rake for you?

Comment: @Gizmomogwai I just installed a linux package manager

Comment: try "which rake" and "which ruby" both on the commandline and in your script triggered by cron, to see if you use the same versions! same with bundle.

Answer (score 0):

When the rake task is executed using the cron job the .bash_profile file is not processed so you need to add the **environment variables** to the sell script.

Find the Ruby Gems path etc using the following:

```
echo $GEM_HOME
echo $GEM_PATH
echo $PATH
```

Add the following to your shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin

export GEM_HOME=/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0

export GEM_PATH=/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global
```

Comment: echo $GEM_HOME and echo $GEM_PATH do not return anything. I tried a gem environnement , and added my GEM PATHS and INSTALLATION DIRECTORY in my .sh script. But it does seem to work.